# List of resources for halachot concerning celiac disease

Tags: halacha, health-safety-shmira

A friend has recently been diagnosed with [celiac disease](https://www.nhs.uk/conditions/coeliac-disease/). This is where individuals develop intolerance to gluten, present in foods such as wheat, rye and barley. This will impact a number of halachic issues. Given the widespread prevalence of celiac disease I was surprised to find that there are few organised resources.

I am looking for a guide, or list, or reference links that are relevant for all issues that affect a person after being diagnosed with celiac disease.

For example: what to do if there is no suitable bread available on shabbat (lechem mishneh), what to do on pesach, etc.

Comment: @dov gave a great guide. Just to be helpful on a practical level, In Israel, they have Gluten Free wheat flour (produced by Kemach Haeretz) which is used for Shabbos by those GF.
Pesach also one can buy GF oat matzah (there is an argument if you are yotzei)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is very comprehensive, 24-page piece from the CrC [here](https://www.crcweb.org/kosher_articles/Celiac%20-%20A%20Guide%20to%20Halachic%20Observance%20(JoHaCS%202010).pdf)

Rabbi Manning has a very helpful sources sheet on what to do in the case of Matzah [here](https://rabbimanning.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/Matza-and-Celiac-Issues.pdf).

And there is a two-part series on the Torah Musing website [here](https://www.torahmusings.com/2014/02/gluten-intolerance-wheat-allergies-and-mitzvos/) and [here](https://www.torahmusings.com/2014/02/gluten-intolerance-wheat-allergies-and-mitzvos-ii/). Part 1 deals with Brachos, Kiddush and the Shabbos Meals and Part 2 deals with Pesach and Succos.